# .NET Core API - Send array of object as FormData via Postman

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

How can I send an array of objects through postman using form-data?

Object

```cs
public class Relations
{
    public short RelationTypeID { get; set; } = 0;
    public List<UserMessageType> UserList { get; set; } = new List<UserMessageType>();
}

public class UserMessageType
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public short MessageTypeID { get; set; }

    public string UserEmailAddress { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

I do not know how can I send a list of Relations through Postman. I read somewhere that I can write multiple Relations but what about child objects. I tried the following on Postman. This is the bulk edit version of the form

```
ConversationID:0
Relations:[{RelationTypeID:1,UserList:[{UserId:15,MessageTypeID:1}]}]
```

This is another try

```
ConversationID:0
Relations:RelationTypeID:1, UserList: UserId:15,MessageTypeID:1
```

Comment: for a better experience, I usually call the get method and get data in JSON view. so use that model of JSON data in order to send data to web API, in the raw body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To post via **form-data**, you can't straight send the value with object nor array.

You can import the below cURL script to Postman by following [these steps](https://dev.to/osejudith/how-to-import-curl-into-postman-and-test-requests-1agg).

```
curl --location --request POST "<YOUR API URL>" \
--form 'ConversationId="1"' \
--form 'Relations[0].RelationTypeID="1"' \
--form 'Relations[0].UserList[0].UserId="15"' \
--form 'Relations[0].UserList[0].MessageTypeID="1"'
```

> API controller

Assume that your API method should be similar as below:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("PostConversation")]
public async Task<JsonResult> PostConversation([FromForm] Conversations conversation)
{
    // Implementation
}
```

> Sample Request and Response in Postman

[image]

> Debugging Output in Visual Studio

[image]