# Mapping list of an object in ASP.NET Core 7 Web API from multipart/form-data request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, multipartform-data, model-binding, asp.net-core-7.0

I have an issue with model binder for bind a list of object in a multipart/form-data request to related C# class property.

This is my request in Swagger:

[post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WqCF.png)

[rest of request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnScG.png)

And in my action method, the `ProductAttributes` count is 0:

[action method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRdBb.jpg)

But I expect the count to be 2.

I also test the post request with Postman:

[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHVzc.png)

but the result is the same.

`CreateProductDto` class:

```
public class CreateProductDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int QIS { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public float DiscountPercentage { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public List<IFormFile> Images { get; set; }
    public List<ProductAttributeCreateDto> ProductAttributes { get; set; }
}
```

`ProductAttributeCreateDto` class:

```
public class ProductAttributeCreateDto
{
    public int AttributeId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

`CreateProduct` action method:

```
[HttpPost("CreateProduct")]
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateProduct([FromForm]CreateProductDto createProductDto)
{ 
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The way you sent the values for `ProductAttributes` in Postman is incorrect. It should be: `ProductAttributes.0.attributeId`: 5, `ProductAttributes.0.value`: string. It is flatten *JSON notation*.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [.NET Core API - Send array of object as FormData via Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71023949)

Comment: Swagger [has issue with enumerables in forms](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1107). I'd suggest using `[FromBody]` jsons, or you'd need some workarounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should send key-value  pairs with postman as below:

[image]

For swagger,it's a known issue and haven't be solved till now,it would send a key value pair(ProductAttributes-json string) instead of the key-value pairs as above,if you insist on testing with swagger, a workaround for you:

Create a custom model binder

```
public class SwaggerArrayBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));

        var values = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        if (values.Length == 0)
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };

        var deserialized = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(values.FirstValue, bindingContext.ModelType, options);

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(deserialized);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

apply the binder:

```
[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(SwaggerArrayBinder))]
    public class ProductAttributeCreateDto
    {
       
        public int AttributeId { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Result:

[image]